# Merge [tag:speech-recognition] with [tag:speech-to-text]

Tags: discussion, tags

[speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) and [speech-to-text](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?